# Python not detected, can`t execute script

Tags: python, shell

I`am just trying to execute python script:

```
python ./helloworld.py
-bash: python: command not found
```

But python is instaled on my PC:

```
whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib/python2.7 /etc/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.6
```

I found that executable named `python` is determined by `$PATH` environment variable.

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

But `which python` command shows nothing

I guess I need to add a python symlink, any suggestions?

Comment: what is the output of `$ which python` and `$ which python3` ?

Comment: python command is an alias of python of python2.7 but looks like you didn't have it. Try to use python2.7 or python3.6

Comment: @hiroprotagonist ```$which python``` shows nothing, but ```which python3``` :/usr/bin/python3 .  However in scrip I use  ```#!/usr/bin/python```

Comment: @AntoineF so the problem is that I dont have python2.7?

Comment: The problem is that you need to figure out which version of python you want to use with this python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As suggested by @hiroprotagonist you should be careful of using this alias because on linux distribution python is used to find python2.7.**

You could create an alias for python point on python3.6.

```
$ alias python=python3.6
```

Or you could add `#!/usr/bin/env python3` at the top of your python script to specify which version of python you want to use.

Comment: that may not be a good idea... all the linux distributions use `python` to point to python 2.7 and `python3` to point to python 3.x.

Comment: as will probably be the case on future linux distributions: there will be `python3` only. aliasing `python` to python 2.7 is against the convention and will break stuff...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions, but can it be dangerous if I dont have python2.7 packets installed at all? See ```whereis python``` output above